# Animated UIButton is reluctant to capture events

Tags: ios, events, animation

My program has a `UIToolBar` which contains a `UITextField` and a `UIButton`. The whole view (`self.view`) goes when the soft keypad comes up. As the `UIToolBar` is moved to a new position, the button sometimes doesn't capture events properly. Several clicks on the button is required to fire a single event.

The following set of code is executed when the keyboard comes up

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-220,320,400);
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 220, 320, 264);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Words falling from the top of screen in iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222466/words-falling-from-the-top-of-screen-in-iphone) - see my answer there, relating to the presentationLayer and touch handling for animating objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,-220,320,400);
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 220, 320, 264);
}completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. Once the animation is done, it requires several clicks. certain part of the button does not respond at all.